# changes in the article display in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

I am trying to get all the articles that I have included to appear on the front page. I have published all of them and also enabled the Front Page column for each of them . But the problem is that one of the articles (say 'main article') occupy the entire width and the others appear side by side. I want of all them to appear taking up the entire width.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Main article</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub Article1</td>
    <td>Sub Article2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Sub Article3</td>
    <td>Sub Article4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but i need them to appear as

```
<table>
<tr><td>Main article</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub Article1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub Article2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub Article3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Sub Article4</td></tr>
</table>
```

is this question relevant and able to be understood...
Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup this in the Menu section. Go to Menu → [Menu where your Front Page assigned]

Than choose menu thread, that response to your Front Page and in it's setup set number of columns to 1 or 0. Thats may help.

Comment: More precisely: it's the Parameters (Basic) section, and what you're interested in changing is Columns parameter. It is set to 2 in your case, and you need to set it to 1. HTH